# What is the antonym for come off?

Tags: vocabulary

> When does baby weight start to come off?

What is the antonym for ***come off***?

Comment: Though your example is a bit confusing. What is "baby weight"? A baby's weight reduction means it starts to "comes off"?

Comment: I think the OP is talking about what we call "baby fat".

Comment: Right. This is confusing. Being a healthcare provider, I'm aware of physiological weight loss of an infant within first few days of its life. If you consider this context, the *coming off* might mean to begin. Also, the verb is used intransitively whereas for the meaning of *drop*, it is generally used transitively. *Come off of something.*

Comment: @MaulikV I've seen "baby weight" used to refer to the weight which a mother typically gains during pregnancy, and which they are often keen to lose after the birth (at least in the weight-obsessed west).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how you're using it, there are two possible "opposites" of *come off*.

First of all, since it seems to be confusing some people, let's first make it clear that the phrase "baby weight" refers *idiomatically* to the weight a mother gains while pregnant, more commonly known as "baby fat".

> The baby fat is starting to **come off**.
>   The sun is so hot that my makeup is starting to **come off**.

The phrase "come off" will always be used to refer transitively to something already implied by the thing that is coming off. In the above two example sentences, the following indirect objects are implied:

> The baby fat is starting to **come off** (my waist).
>   The sun is so hot that my makeup is starting to **come off** (my face).

As user3169 pointed out, *put on* is one possible antonym, although it turns the baby weight into the object instead of the subject of the sentence. And as aboce, an indirect object is implied:

> How much baby weight did *you* **put on** (your body)?
>   *That model* **puts on** (her face) so much makeup that her face started getting rashes.

There's another antonym that simply means "not come off", which is *stay on*.

> The baby weight has **stayed on** (my body) for too long.
>   Once you get a tattoo, it **stays on** (your body) for life.

This one can be used in replacement with "come off" to mean "not come off" anywhere that's used.

Comment: http://www.hlntv.com/article/2012/09/12/jessica-simpson-baby-weight-realistic-expectations-christine-avanti what's *come off* here in the third bullet?

Comment: "But it will only come off with effort and commitment." The phrase "come off" here refers to the exact same "come off" as in the question. The antonym you'd use here would be "stay on" as such: "Without effort and commitment, that baby weight is **staying on**."

Comment: In reference to Maulik's article - come off in that articles means - to happen

Answer (score 1):

The antonym of *come off* as used in the question is **put on**.

> How much weight did you **put on**?
>   That was a lot of weight you **put on**.

referring to a weight increase. Another example:

> When it got hot outside her clothes **came off**.
>   When it started snowing more clothing was **put on**.

Comment: don't you think it means what you said when it's used transitively?

Comment: I added some more examples. Though the OP asked about antonyms, not the verb form.

Comment: One point: while you can say "When did your weight start to come off?" you can NOT say "When did your weight start to put on?".

Comment: @BobRodes- Yes, you'd have to ask, "When did your weight start to **go up**?"